# Spring can't get mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a REST API with Spring and Hibernate.

When I run the server it returns no errors, but I can't access my links.

Here is my config file:

***spring.xml***

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.bloggy.spring" />
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_bloggy?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
 </bean>

<bean id="txManager"
      class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
```

And that is my web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/resources/spring.xml</param-value>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/resources/dao.xml</param-value>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/resources/service.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "users")
public class UserController {
  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<User> getUsers() {
    return userService.listUsers();
  }
}
```

Comment: what URL you are trying to access and what is the path that this mentioned for your rest service

Comment: I am trying to access http://localhost:8080/api/users

I am adding the controller to the question

Comment: It does no difference :/

Comment: can you paste console log after made request ?

Comment: It logs nothing just the server startup logs.

Comment: did you enable annotation config?

Comment: Yes. Right above the sessionFactory bean i've put 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.bloggy.spring.controller" />. but for some reason it does not show up in the question

Comment: Are you deploying this application in tomcat or some other server? If yes, you should also append the name of war file too in the url. Unless, you have defined some mapping for that

Comment: I have defined war name my-bloggy but the http://localhost:8080/my-bloggy/api/users still returns error 404 with no logs in the console

Comment: Can you attach tomcat logs?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5EXKYded

Comment: clear your cache and try. something wrong with the server or you are deploying an old war. at the time of deploying `MyBloggy` doesn't initialize any spring beans. It's  usually visible in logs unless you've disabled it

Comment: @Andro according to the log its not starting as spring application. how did you build this application? I think this is a maven project . Try building this from terminal and then deploy it to tomcat.

Comment: @Kid101 the problem was in the deployment artifact of tomcat. Thank you very much I have resolved my problem.

Comment: glad it helped, let me add it as an answer, please accept and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As visible in [logs](http://pastebin.com/5EXKYded) the application `MyBloggy` doesn't actually initialize any spring beans. There is a problem with cache or the war file deployed on the tomcat. Ideally, At the time of deploying a `war` all the beans initialized can be seen in the logs unless disabled. Make sure that you are deploying a correct `war` on the server.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ken mentioned In order to expose your API as a REST AP you need to use @RestController or if you want to use @Controller then use @ResponseBody annotation.

With regards to your issue I think you need to define your RequestMapping as

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "api")
public class UserController {
  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<User> getUsers() {
    return userService.listUsers();
  }
}
```

Or

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "api/users")
public class UserController {
  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<User> getUsers() {
    return userService.listUsers();
  }
}
```

Please see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using @Controller annotation, but if you want expose REST webservice, you need use @RestController or @ResponseBody

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "users")
public class UserController
```